# regex: match everything until a new lines comes without space after it

Tags: php, regex

I have this example:

```
This is a simple test text.
Yet another line.
START: This is the part that
 needs match.
This part does not need
 capture.
Wherever else text.
```

I want to match this part:

```
START: This is the part that
     needs capture.
```

The point is I know the `START:` is there and it ends with a new line that has anything but a space after it.

I have tried a lot of combinations starting from: `START: (.*?)`

I have plaid around with \r and anything I could think of to match only if it has no white-space.

I am not a noob asking because I am lazy. I spent a few hours before asking.

Comment: Also, for what reason do you want to match the "START" paragraph, but noch the "END" paragraph. They both match the description you have given in the title. Or are "START" and "END" literally significant? Or do you just want the first match? A bit more detail would greatly help :)

Comment: Downvoted : 1. Nothing tried by OP , 2. Requirements not clearly mentioned.

Comment: @tntu: So the "START" is significant? (i.e. you only want to match paragraphs, that begin wie `START: `?

Comment: I have edited. I have gotten to this point: START: (.*?) now I need to match linebreak without whitespace after it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```
preg_match(
    '/^         # Start of line
    START:\     # Match "START: "
    .*          # Match any characters except newline
    \r?\n       # Match newline
    (?:         # Try to match...
     ^          # from the start of the line:
     \ +        #  - one or more spaces
     .*         #  - any characters except newline
     \r?\n      #  - newline
    )*          # Repeat as needed/mx', 
    $subject)
```

This assumes that all lines are newline-terminated.

Comment: I'm mobile now but I can't wait to test this. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to find more than one of these paragraphs, use `preg_match_all()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I have to make some adjustments but it got me on the right path. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work correctly with your example test.

The workaround is a token to replace the new lines before the preg_match (that are restored after!) and the Ungreedy modifier at the end of regex (U)

```
<?php

$token = '#####';

$text = <<<TXT
This is a simple test text.
Yet another line.
START: This is the part that
 needs match.
This part does not need
 capture.
Wherever else text.
TXT;

$text = str_replace("\n", $token, $text);

if (preg_match('/(?P<match>START:(.)*)(' . $token . '){1}[^ ]+/Uu', $text, $matches))
{
    $match = str_replace($token, "\n", $matches['match']);
    var_dump($match);
}

$text = str_replace($token, "\n", $text);
```

Output will be:

```
string(42) "START: This is the part that
 needs match."
```